# Ошибка Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, for

При запуске данного кода возникает ошибка Timeout Errorю В чем проблема кода?

```
var fibonacciNumbers = [1, 1];
var numbersQuantity = 7;

for (var i = fibonacciNumbers.length; i < fibonacciNumbers.length + numbersQuantity; i++) {
  fibonacciNumbers[i] = i;
}

console.log(fibonacciNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле увеличиваете длину массива, которую используете в условии остановки цикла.

```js
var fibonacciNumbers = [1, 1];
var numbersQuantity = 7;

var startingLength = fibonacciNumbers.length;
for (var i = fibonacciNumbers.length; i < startingLength + numbersQuantity; i++) {
   fibonacciNumbers[i] = fibonacciNumbers[i - 2] + fibonacciNumbers[i - 1]; 
}

console.log(fibonacciNumbers);
```

Comment: Боже, точно!
Большое спасибо, я очень невнимателен))

Comment: @НикитаПопов Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.